# No internet in Ubuntu server

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, internet

I installed ubuntu server in my Virtualbox. But while installing I haven't connected to the internet. After it installed I connected to the internet and while trying to `apt-get update`, it shows Temporary failure in name resolution.

Tried many commands from the internet to restart the network manager, but it shows

> Failed to restart network-manager.service: Unit
> network-manager.service not found

PS: Network : Bridged adapter

Comment: What is the output of `file /usr/sbin/NetworkManager` and `apt list --installed | grep network-manager`?

Comment: @Kulfy The reply of the first command was "No such file or directory". and the second one was "apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts".

Comment: Do you see anything like `logical name: en` in the output of `lshw -C network`?

Comment: @Kulfy I think I should reinstall the server.

Comment: @Kulfy I do not believe that *server* edition comes with Network Manager. It, instead, uses netplan.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `ip addr show` as well as: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`

Comment: @chili555 Thanks for the reply. I reinstalled it now while connected to the internet. It now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

NetworkManager is a system network service that manages your network devices and connections and attempts to keep network connectivity active when available.

You can check whether the NetworkManager is running or not using this command :

```
sudo systemctl status NetworkManager
```

If it is disabled you can enable it with this command :

```
sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager
```

After enabling the NetworkManager you can start it using this command :

```
sudo systemctl start NetworkManager
```

In case the NetworkManager is not installed then you need to install it from Linux repositories. However to do so you need to have an internet connection.

If the above mentioned method didn't work you can set up connection manually.
In order to do so you need to find the network device that has internet connection to it.

If you have NetworkManager installed and it is still not working then make sure that managed state is set to *false* in the NetworkManager configuration file before proceeding to set the connection manually.

```
$cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf 

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

To check all the available network devices use this command:

```
ip addr show
```

[image: ip addr show result]

In the above image `ens3` is the network device. If you are working with wireless adapter the name will start from `wl`.

Once you have figured out the adapter, you need to edit the `interfaces` file present in :

```
/etc/network
```

Before you edit the file make sure the interface is down, use the command :

```
sudo ifdown <name of the interface>
e.g: sudo ifdown ens3
```

Open the interfaces file with `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces` and add the following in it

```
allow-hotplug <name of interface>
iface <name of interface> inet dhcp

e.g: 
allow-hotplug ens3
iface ens3 inet dhcp
```

Save the file and start the interface again with the command :

```
sudo ifup <name of the interface>
e.g : sudo ifup ens3
```

Now you should have working internet in your system. You can check the status with `ip addr show` command.

Comment: `$cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf ` There is no file called NetworkManager.conf in the directory. Also it says `ifdown` command not found.

Comment: That means NetworkManager is not installed. May I know what version of Ubuntu server are you using. If you are missing a lot of tools then it was not installed correctly.
You should try reinstalling it

Comment: Recent *server* versions use neither Network Manager nor `/etc/network/interfaces`. They use netplan.

Comment: @WhiteMars I downloaded the latest version from the ubuntu site and installed as a regular ubuntu installation. Anyway I reinstalled it, and now its fixed.

Comment: @chili555 thank you for telling that, got to learn something new :D.